# How does Nuxt generate static html from markdown file?

Tags: nuxt.js

This is most solution I found:

```js
/// nuxt.config.js

export default {
  ......
  generate: {
    routes: fs.readdirSync('markdownDir').map(filename => {
      return {
        route: `/articles/${path.basename(filename, '.md')}`,
        content: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve('markdownDir', filename))
      }
    })
  },
}
```

```html
/// _articleDetail.vue

<template>
    <div>
        <div class='markdown' v-html='html'></div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
......
  async asyncData({params, content}) {
    return {id: params.id, html: processMarkdown(content)}
  },
}
</script>
```

**It will generate all Html with article id,but those Html file dosen't contains the real markdown content.It's just like:**

```html
......
<div class='markdown'>
(I need markdown content here,Not by js!)
</div>
<script src="/_nuxt/844cb81.js" defer></script>
```

`/_nuxt/844cb81.js` has the real markdown content! I think it's will be bad in SEO.
So I want a solution that can directly generate html that contains origin markdown content.

Comment: Is your `target` set to `static` (default is `server`) and `ssr` set to `true` (default value) ? One solution to debug this is to disable JS and check the source code of the page, you will be sure if it's properly generated ! :D

Comment: @kissu Thinks,`target` is `static`,and try `ssr` both`true`,`false`,don't work!

Comment: How do you build your app ?

Comment: @kissu `npm run generate`

Answer (score 0):

Figured out,I have made a mistake.

**all `NuxtLink` that points to `article-detail page` must be wrote `in static`,that means you can't write them like:**

```
// the `loading` default is true

<div v-if='loading'>
    loading...
</div>
<div v-else>
    <NuxtLink v-for='id in idList' :to="'/article/'+id"/>
</div>
```

Seems that Nuxt have compiled `.vue` file in generating static routes,and only invoked `asyncData()` function,use default `data` to compile.